# Store the Value Permanent?

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

`I have an app, In this signIn through the dropbox and after the signIn I got the vale of below I declared:`

`DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;`

**What I want is :**

*I want to use this value(get this value) after my Phone Reboot.*

`Or`

*I want to store this Value Permanent.*

***`For better understand have a look on this Link  :`*** [DROPBOX_REFERENCE_LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android)

**For this WHAT I tried :**

1. I did static but it's working fine till Phone is Switch on. Does not mean !
2. Use SharedPrefrence but `I have to put this value into the String` but In the time of typeCast , I am not able to convert this String value into the DropboxAPI Generic Type.

LIKE :

```
String s = mDBApi_From_Prefrence;
DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi = `TypeCast From String s to DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>`
```

What Should I do store this mBDApi value `PERMANENT`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store this value to a [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) Database as a BLOB type and fetch it again. Databases remain persistent for the app even after reboot.

Comment: Like If I am using VARCHAR, I pass this value through String And What in the case of BLOB ?

Comment: No need to typecast. Use the following code sample for some help...

SQLiteDatabase db               =   dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    
    String sql                      =   "INSERT INTO DBIN (mdbapi) VALUES(?)";
    SQLiteStatement insertStmt      =   db.compileStatement(sql);
    insertStmt.clearBindings();
    insertStmt.bindBlob(1, this.mDBApi);
    insertStmt.executeInsert();
    db.close();

Comment: I am not getiing help from this